# How to use Angulartics2 with ApplicationInsights

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-application-insights, angulartics2

We setup applicationinsights as explain [official doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web#setup-npm-only-ignore-if-using-snippet). We setup applicationInsights in `app.component.ts` constructor.

We want to user [Angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2) to managed google analitycs and applicationinsights.

However, Angulartics2  needs [appInsights to be global](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/blob/master/src/lib/providers/appinsights/appinsights.ts#L33). By declaring appInsights inside of the constructor of `app.component.ts`, `appInsights` is not global.

if we setup `window['appInsights'] = new ApplicationInsights(....)`, everything works as expected. What is the correct way to use application insight with angulartics2. [Doc page](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2/tree/master/src/lib/providers/appinsights) is not very useful.

Comment: It's unfortunate that they designed their API that way.

Comment: We finally not use Angulartics2. We use a custom services. I think is not ready for the new appInsigth library 2.1.1. Even appInsigth has a bit of confusion about which current version is correct if 1.0.20 or 2.1.1.